# How to solve Mininet SDN Custom ring and mesh topologis which creates loop problems and can't be pinged?

Tags: loops, sdn, mininet, topology

I have searched a lot in google about this problem. but couldn't find anything to solve it. 
there is a problem when we create a SDN topology in mininet which there are multipath connections causing loop problems while no problem happens when we use linear or tree topology in Mininet. 
[Mininet Custom Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq3EX.jpg)
I am using ODL Carbon with this but also doesn't work. 
is there any solution for the topology and mininet? what exactly I have to do?

[didn't undrestand anything from this link too](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2012-February/000695.html)
this is my mininet 16 switches with 2 hosts

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
from subprocess import call

def myNetwork():

    net = Mininet( topo=None,
                   build=False,
                   ipBase='10.0.0.0/8')

    info( '*** Adding controller\n' )
    c0=net.addController(name='c0',
                      controller=RemoteController,
                      ip='192.168.43.140',
                      protocol='tcp',
                      port=6653)

    info( '*** Add switches\n')
    s14 = net.addSwitch('s14', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s7 = net.addSwitch('s7', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s3 = net.addSwitch('s3', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s10 = net.addSwitch('s10', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s13 = net.addSwitch('s13', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s6 = net.addSwitch('s6', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s16 = net.addSwitch('s16', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s1 = net.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s9 = net.addSwitch('s9', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s5 = net.addSwitch('s5', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s2 = net.addSwitch('s2', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s12 = net.addSwitch('s12', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s15 = net.addSwitch('s15', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s8 = net.addSwitch('s8', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s4 = net.addSwitch('s4', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s11 = net.addSwitch('s11', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)

    info( '*** Add hosts\n')
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.1', defaultRoute=None)
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.2', defaultRoute=None)

    info( '*** Add links\n')
    net.addLink(s1, s2)
    net.addLink(s2, s3)
    net.addLink(s3, s4)
    net.addLink(s4, s5)
    net.addLink(s5, s6)
    net.addLink(s6, s7)
    net.addLink(s2, s8)
    net.addLink(s8, s9)
    net.addLink(s9, s10)
    net.addLink(s10, s11)
    net.addLink(s12, s11)
    net.addLink(s13, s14)
    net.addLink(s14, s15)
    net.addLink(s15, s16)
    net.addLink(s16, s12)
    net.addLink(s12, s7)
    net.addLink(s13, s8)
    net.addLink(s1, h2)
    net.addLink(s16, h1)

    info( '*** Starting network\n')
    net.build()
    info( '*** Starting controllers\n')
    for controller in net.controllers:
        controller.start()

    info( '*** Starting switches\n')
    net.get('s14').start([c0])
    net.get('s7').start([c0])
    net.get('s3').start([c0])
    net.get('s10').start([c0])
    net.get('s13').start([c0])
    net.get('s6').start([c0])
    net.get('s16').start([c0])
    net.get('s1').start([c0])
    net.get('s9').start([c0])
    net.get('s5').start([c0])
    net.get('s2').start([c0])
    net.get('s12').start([c0])
    net.get('s15').start([c0])
    net.get('s8').start([c0])
    net.get('s4').start([c0])
    net.get('s11').start([c0])

    info( '*** Post configure switches and hosts\n')

    CLI(net)
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    myNetwork()
```

Comment: Are you able to `pingall` with you snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing errors?

Please try the `pingall` command in mininet to create the topology.
On a frank note, I had too many issues in regard with ODL "Carbon" and I moved to ODL "beryllium" which is very stable till date. I am researcher in SDN and ODL with Iperf.

Comment: I have also downloaded and used ODL beryllium version too. but in my topology which is a multipath topology, pingall command doesn't work and it shows an infinite loop.
but with floodlight it is ok while I turn down a link, it can't be converged.
Have you ever create a ring or mesh topology in mininet ?

Comment: @RaminRamesh I have worked with ring and mesh topology creation. Can you share me the python script which you are working with.

Comment: @RaminRamesh I will work on this code and surely come back to you. Good day!

Comment: thank you so much. please inform me if or ifnot this work. 
also test this topo with ODL: 

sudo mn --topo torus,3,3 --controller remote,ip=127.0.0.2, port=6633

I am not able to run torus mininet topology in odl and test link failures too.

Comment: Hello @RaminRamesh till I come back to you, try to explore this link "http://pakiti.com/sdn-101-using-mininet-and-sdn-controllers/" and just think over how it works. But, surely I will work on your script. Good day ahead!

Comment: with neither of odl carbon nor beryllium, i am not able to create torus topology in ubuntu 18.04 64bit. 

also in floodlight, it is not possible to down a link then ping. the topology can't be converged again.

Comment: @RaminRamesh the script is working for me in the ubuntu 14.04 LTS version. Please check the ubuntu 18 version, whether it is compatible to adapt to that environment. Thank you.